# PHP closing a connection early. script hangs if any output is done

Tags: php

I'm early closing a connection to client with this:

```
static public function early_close( $output )
{
   ignore_user_abort(true);
   echo $output;

   // Disable gzip compression in apache, as it can result in this request being buffered until it is complete,
   // regardless of other settings.
   if (function_exists('apache_setenv')) {
       apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
   }

    // get the size of the output
    $size = ob_get_length();

    // send headers to tell the browser to close the connection
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    header('Connection: close');
    header("Content-Encoding: none"); // To disable Apache compressing anything

    // IF PHP-FM
    // fastcgi_finish_request();

    // flush all output
    if( ob_get_level() > 0 )
    {
        ob_end_flush();
        ob_get_level()? ob_flush():null;
        flush();
    }

    // if you're using sessions, this prevents subsequent requests
    // from hanging while the background process executes
    if( session_id() )
    {
        session_write_close();
    }
}
```

Works ok, but after this event if some script outputs anything (either by echo'ing or by adding a new header) the script stops executing from that point.
I've tried to start output buffering after early closing and then discarding it but it does not work:

```
Server::early_close();
ob_start();
heavy_work();
ob_clean();
```

Any ideas?
Using php 5.3.x

Comment: Is a simple `die()`  verboten?

Comment: I `die()` does not help here because the requeriments are to answer client as soon as server receives the order to do `heavy_work`. Client does not need to wait to `heavy_work` to end. A `die()` placed instead of `Server::early_close()` would avoid `heavy_work()` from execute.

Comment: Don't try to keep a _webserver_ thread running if the HTTP reply is over. Make it an async job. Gearman and the like can take care of a lot of the gritty details of that for you, but any work(-queue) will do.

Comment: I'll try that alternative, but I'm afraid I cannot use that on the server.

Comment: I can't help to ask. Why would anything you are doing in `heavy_work()` output anything or modify headers? The response to the request has already been sent upon `flush()` so you have no endpoint to respond to anyway?

Comment: Why are you trying to early close the connection? Do you want to do heavy background tasks without impacting the user?

Comment: @tomahaug I do not intend to output anything from that point. It is true what you say but because sometimes I accidentally leave an echo, sometimes php throws errors that outputs strings, if I use some lib that outputs something... I know I can avoid all of those by removing all echo'es, and disabling error output, but I want to know why my script stops and if I can "catch" any output done inside heavy work so that doesn't stop the process execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic code to do that is:

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort();              // optional ob_start();

echo ('Text the user will see');

$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();                   // Strange behaviour, will not work
flush();                          // Unless both are called !

// Do processing here
sleep(30);

echo('Text user will never see');
```

Otherwise, I advise the following read if you want to do asynchronous calls: [Methods for asynchronous processes in PHP](http://davenewson.com/dev/methods-for-asynchronous-processes-in-php)

Comment: I properly close the connection, what seems to fail is if there is any output in my heavy work the script stops executing, and I want to know why and if I can avoid it.

Comment: Are you sure it is about some output? Isn't there a timeout/memory limit/etc?

Comment: Yes, when I place an echo inside "heavy work" it does not ends its execution, it just stops at the same line the echo is executed. When this echo is commented, script ends successfully.

Comment: If you test the exact above, does it work? If yes, rewrite your code starting from it and add piece by piece (test each time) until it "breaks". :)

Comment: Your code as it is does not seem to work to me, I had to add `ob_start` at the beginning. Once I did this yes, I tested and code reaches the end, so I guess I have something else in my code that causes that problem. Because you made me realize php correctly handles this I give you the bounty. Thank you very much.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. This is not the correct solution and should not be marked as such. I am using httpie on the command line on a Mac to send the request to a script via Apache.

Comment: I take it back. It was simply not working on MAMP (My local dev environment). I am now investigating why. It may be because both client and server are on the same IP (localhost).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you shouldn't take this route. Http requests should be as short as possible to improve usability.

If some "heavy processing" should be performed, you can "schedule" it using some sort of queue. A separate process/daemon on the server can pick up these jobs from the queue to perform them. The http application can then check if such a job is still waiting to be processed / has been started / is done.

There are many libraries available to facilitate this: [Gearman](http://gearman.org/), [ØMQ](http://zeromq.org/), [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), etc.

Http requests aren't really suited for long operations, which is why you run into all sorts of problems when trying to do so :)

**UPDATE**

If you're unable to use libraries (like Gearman, etc) on the server, you could build your own file- or db-based queue, push "commands" into the queue from within your application, and have a cronjob read that queue and perform those tasks.

Comment: That's why I'm closing the connection as soon as I can

Comment: You're relying on that the fact that the process keeps running in order to perform desired operations, but you have no way of guarantying this will succeed, nor reporting failures to the user.

Comment: +1 using a background-task solution (even a roll-your-own implementation) is a better idea and more robust than relying on orphaned http requests to complete without misbehaving.

Comment: I agree it is not a clean solution (I plan to use a library/develop my own to better handle this) I was just curious about how could a simple echo hang my execution.

Comment: How do you consider not taking this route. You need to do what you need to. And sometimes, it is just not possible to just assume that the scripts will run in a timely manner.

Comment: I take it back. It was simply not working on MAMP (My local dev environment). I am now investigating why. It may be because both client and server are on the same IP (localhost).

Answer (score 1):

You need an echo chr(0); after the echo $output;. Sending a null byte will force the browser to end the connection. Also, I'm assuming there is an ob_start()  before the Server::early_close()? If not, you would need that for ob_get_length to work properly.

Comment: Yes, there is an `ob_start()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments to date, I recommend replacing your current solution with an AJAX request on page load.  Instead of closing your connection early and continuing to process on the server, serve your response as you typically would and add an AJAX request to add any additional processing after the page is loaded on the client.  This removes the issue of extraneous output entirely, and you can also send any success / failure messages back to the user.

Another solution is to queue your work in a table or memory and set up a cron to process in the background.

Comment: This script is already requested via an ajax call. What I found is that the request timedout if the early close wasn't placed.

Comment: Oh, well in that case you can extend the timeout and not close the connection early. Although if you have long running background processes I highly recommend a cron instead (again with long timeout).